# How to Force user to login to view catalog

Tags: magento2, customer, catalog, login

I am beginner in Magneto and  I have install magneto 2.1.15 using WAMP server.  I want to force user to login first then redirect to home page to view catalog and other menu. Please suggest where exactly I need to change.

Comment: can you tell me you want to add this feature using any extension or you want to add this functionality in your extension?

Comment: https://github.com/bitExpert/magento2-force-login - check this free github module

Comment: thanking you Jinesh and Aravind.

Answer (score 1):

**Link For Free Extension :-**

[Force Login](https://marketplace.magento.com/bitexpert-magento2-force-customer-login.html?utm_source=mageplaza&utm_medium=mageplaza&utm_campaign=mageplaza-review&utm_content=Force%20Login)

[Force Login Module for Magento® 2](https://github.com/bitExpert/magento2-force-login)